# Is there any new ways to detect if the scroll event was created by User or Animation

Tags: jquery, scroll

I know there are multiple **Q**'s asking for this. But those are pretty old and not active, Is there any new methods or workarounds or ideas for this.

What I want is to differentiate the scroll events.?

Let's say, am adding a class `max-limit` on a function and after triggering an animation:

```
$(this).addClass('max-limit');
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: thS.offset().top - window.innerHeight / 2
}, 500);
```

The thing is, after this am removing it on a scroll function:

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
   $('.thisClass').removeClass('max-limit');
});
```

but now because am triggering an animation after the `addClass` the class automatically removes due to my scroll function, what I want is to **only remove this class if a user is scrolling the page.** Any help would be appreciated.thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) you can use:

> [:animated Selector](https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/): Select all elements that are in the progress of an animation at the time the selector is run.

Hence your  scroll event will be:

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(e){
     if (!$('html,body').is(':animated')) {
         $('.thisClass').removeClass('max-limit');
     }
 });
```